# Vector bosons: polar vectors or axial vectors?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, standard-model, bosons, gauge

The $W$ and $Z$ bosons are known as *vector* bosons, because they have non-zero spin.

**How do we know whether they are *axial* or *polar* vectors?**

Context:

I am reading about a technique called *Operator Product Expansion* in which it is possible to write an effective hamiltonian $\mathcal{H}_{eff}$ in terms of short distance and long distance effects, parameterised, respectively, by the *Wilson coefficients* $\mathcal{C}_i$ and the *Wilson operators* $\mathcal{O}_i$:
$$ \mathcal{H}_{eff} \propto \sum_i \mathcal{C}_i \mathcal{O}_i $$

Now, it turns out that in some theories the $\mathcal{O}_9$ and $\mathcal{O}_{10}$ operators correspond to vector and axial-vector mediated processes, i.e. processes mediated by either the $Z$ or the $W$ bosons.
I don't know which operator corresponds to which particle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For massless gauge bosons the only meaningful way to transform under parity is like polar vectors since they have to transform as $i\partial_\mu$ in the covariant derivative. For massive gauge boson, one in principle doesn't have this constraint, although one could assign a parity as for massless vectors assuming the mass comes from spontaneous symmetry breaking.

But there is a further problem here with the electroweak interactions that badly break parity (think about the fact that the $Z$ couples to left- and right-handed currents differently). There is no parity assignment to the $Z$ that makes the theory P-invariant.

You should actually look at the way they transform under $CP$ (I am neglecting the small CP-violating contributions form the CKM matrix). The $Z$ and the photon transform in the same way under $CP$ (think about the fact that they result from a mixing that doesn't break CP since the Higgs boson is CP neutral), that is they are neutral ``polar'' vectors, meaning that under CP: $A_\mu(t,x)\rightarrow -\eta_{\mu\mu}A_\mu(t,-x)$ (indexes not summed) with $\eta_{\mu\mu}=\mathrm{diag}(1,-1,-1,-1)$. With this transformation the SM lagrangian is CP invariant (again, neglecting the small sources of CP violations).

If you want to discuss the case where CP is violated, you need to consider CPT as the discrete symmetry. CPT is certainly conserved under the usual conditions (i.e. Lorentz invariance, microcausality, locality, ...). Under CPT they transform as $i\partial_\mu$ (remember that T is anti-unitary) and therefore $CPT: A_\mu(t,x)\rightarrow \eta_{\mu\mu}A_\mu(-t,x)$.